# why is it called longpolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

I've read and done (for my self) [How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)

But why is this called "long-polling", It just polls when it's done on both success and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal poll asks once in a very quick back and forth between client and server.

A long poll is kept open and idle for a *long time*, possibly sending data several times while the connection is open. Hence *long* polling.

Comment: wow. thanks. but could you give an example on how I'm able to send several times? this i don't understand

Comment: @Jason The server stays in an infinite loop, which keeps the connection open. The server simply writes output every once in a while. For example: `while (true) { echo 'foo'; sleep(1000); }` The client can read this data as it comes in. That's a real long poll.